# Is it possible to set the BizTalk receive location such that it will process the files in sequence?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Is it possible to set the BizTalk receive location such that it will process the files (say, already have 10 files in the folder) in sequence, ordered by the file creation timestamp?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to use the default File adapter here, as it does not support this kind of functionality.

One of your options might be to use the [File Adapter Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578623(v=bts.10).aspx) (from the BizTalk Server SDK) and further customize it to publish the files in order to the MessageBox. [Here](http://pamelayang.blogspot.be/2010/02/custom-biztalk-file-adapter-biztalk.html) you can find an interesting blogpost to get you started.

Other options might be:

- Use an orchestration to re-sequence your files.
- Develop a Windows Service to re-arrange the files in order and use a system like MSMQ/SQL to (temporary) store the files in order.

Answer (score 0):

I must say it is a "mission impossible". Please note the "File Creation Date" is not the time file was dropped in your receive location. it is the "creation" date

So whenever you picked a file and want to decide should you process it or wait for a "earlier" file , You have no idea if next second or next day, another file with an earlier creation date will be dropped in your folder.